# Looping through rows and columns of spreadsheet and putting data using ignite infragistics

Tags: angular, infragistics

I am new to ignite spreadsheet of Infragistics. I am using this to read an excel spreadsheet and render template on the browser using angular. I am able to successfully render the excel template on the browser. I also need to read an xml file and populate the excel with those values. I have also achieved reading of the file.
The challenge I am facing is populating the excel with the values read from the xml file.

For example , I need to put value 100 at positon  row 010 and col 010 as seen on the sheet. I am trying to see a mechanism where I can get column collection and row collection and loop through. Does anybody have an idea or come across it.

This is what the excel looks like

[image]

xml file

```
<Reports>
<Report>
    <Name>F 20.04</Name>    
    <ReportVal>
    <ReportRow>10</ReportRow>
    <ReportCol>10</ReportCol>
    <Val>100</Val>
    </ReportVal>    
    <ReportVal>
    <ReportRow>10</ReportRow>
    <ReportCol>11</ReportCol>
    <Val>200</Val>
    </ReportVal>    
    <ReportVal>
    <ReportRow>10</ReportRow>
    <ReportCol>12</ReportCol>
    <Val>0</Val>
    </ReportVal>    
    <ReportVal>
    <ReportRow>20</ReportRow>
    <ReportCol>10</ReportCol>
    <Val>600</Val>
    </ReportVal>    
    <ReportVal>
    <ReportRow>20</ReportRow>
    <ReportCol>11</ReportCol>
    <Val>500</Val>
    </ReportVal>    
    <ReportVal>
    <ReportRow>20</ReportRow>
    <ReportCol>12</ReportCol>
    <Val>0</Val>
    </ReportVal>        
  </Report> 
</Reports>
```

**Angular component**

```
ngOnInit() {
   // loading xml data
    this.spreadsheetService.loadXML().subscribe((data) => {
      this.parseXML(data)
        .then((data) => {
         // console.log('The data is' + data);
          this.xmlItems = data;
        });
    });
  }

parseXML(data) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: one-variable-per-declaration
      let k: string | number,
      r: string | number,
        // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
        arr = [],
        // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
        reportVal = [],
        // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
        parser = new xml2js.Parser(
          {
            trim: true,
            explicitArray: true
          });
      parser.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
        const obj = result.Reports;
        // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
        for (k in obj.Report) {
          // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
          let item = obj.Report[k];


          // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
          for (r in item.ReportVal) {
            // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
            let item1 = item.ReportVal[r];

            reportVal.push({
              ReportRow: item1.ReportRow[0],
              ReportCol: item1.ReportCol[0],
              Val: item1.Val[0]
            });

          }

          arr.push({
            Name: item.Name[0],
            ReportVal: reportVal,
          });
        //  console.log(arr);
        }
        resolve(arr);
      });
    });
  }


loading the excel

    public openFile(input: HTMLInputElement): void {
        if (input.files == null || input.files.length === 0) {
          return;
        }
    
       // console.log("Files:" + input.files[0].name);
    
        ExcelUtility.load(input.files[0]).then((w) => {
          this.spreadsheet.workbook = w;
          //var colIndex = this.spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets(0).getRegion('E10:k10');
          var colIndex = this.spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets(0).rows(10).cells().item;
    
          for (const idx in colIndex){
              console.log(idx);
          }
    
    
    
        }, (e) => {
          console.error('Workbook Load Error:' + e);
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through `cells` collection will return only the cells which already have been used, in your case nothing. You should iterate and create cells using `for` loop like this:

```
var cells = this.spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets(0).rows(10).cells();
for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
  var currentCell = cells.item(c);
}
```

More information in the API [here](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/api/docs/typescript/latest/classes/worksheetcellcollection.html#item).